# What does the warning sign over battery icon represent?

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, battery

The battery icon on my laptop has a warning sign when plugged in: [image] to a laptop dock via a USB C cable.

When I click on the icon, I get this popup.  Just a warning icon and no further information.  There also aren't any tooltips to indicate what is going on.

[image]

If I disconnect the laptop or connect it directly to the power supply, the warning sign goes away.  The laptop works perfectly fine with the warning icon on, but I am curious why it is displayed.

P.S. I am on Windows 20H2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This icon means that the power being supplied is not sufficient to charge the battery at normal speed. It will charge, but it will either be lower or not fast enough that the battery drains. Basically, the charger itself provides a higher current than the USB port and it warns you that you should not expect to charge your battery in this mode to 100% or it may take a really long time to not possible.

Also, it may not be able to actually charge in case of a high load.

Comment: That makes sense.  There is probably a numeric voltage value at which the warning icon appears.  I ran a stress [online stress test](https://silver.urih.com/) to tax the CPUs to 100%, while simultaneously running Age of Empires II to beat the GPUs.  I ran it for about 10-15 minutes.  The battery remained at 100%.  So my conclusion is that the dock supplies a bit less power than Windows thinks is sufficient, but enough to keep the battery at 100%.

Comment: If you discharge the battery to a lot less... say 30% power and repeat your test, I'm sure it will either remain at 30% or decrease. Whereas with a normal wall charger it would still charge.

Comment: Update.  My laptop discharged to 1%.  I connected it back up to the dock and started charging the laptop.  The warning sign disappeared.  It charged back up all the way reasonably quickly.  When it hit the 100%, [this notification](https://i.imgur.com/D9lCeCa.png) came up.  When I clicked on it, it took me to [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-usb-c-problems-f4e0e529-74f5-cdae-3194-43743f30eed2#chargingslowly), which details USB related issues.

Comment: @AngryHacker so it seems the charger has a way of detecting reaching 100% and in order to protect the battery it goes into slow charging mode such that the battery will drain more and charge less, so this is a good thing. I'm sure if and when the battery goes below... say 90% the charger will switch back to full charging mode. Its just windows that doesn't know this is actually wanted and warns... you know, just in case.